# Is there a sudo for os.remove()

Tags: python

I have an existing file I want to remove, and I get the following error when trying to remove it:

```
os.remove(input_path)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Is there any way to remove a file  that already exists, other than doing:

```
subprocess.call(['rm', input_path])
```

Comment: Why would `subprocess.call` help?

Comment: How exactly would the `subprocess.call` line avoid the problem?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to remove an existing file. Is `input_path` a directory by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're getting a "permission denied" error, it is clear there's a "mismatch" between the permissions of the file (or its parent directory), and those of the user running the python process.

The best practice, instead of looking for "shortcuts" in the form of `sudo`, is to fix the permissions, either of the file being deleted, or the user running the python process.

Permissions are used for a reason. You're risking getting into troubles if you choose to void/bypass them by using tricks such as `sudo`.

Comment: I have a restricted user in an rssh chroot jail who can create files with that restricted UID (a dropbox).  Unfortunately both sftp and rsync permit the rssh user to create subdirectories with files with his UID.  I have another user (different UID) where I 'manage' that restricted UIDs files removing them after processing.  But I found that I cannot remove files in the subdirectories because of permissions.  Adding a /etc/sudoers line to permit rm -rf /home/dropbox/SUBDIR/*  works, but python needs a subprocess.to execute sudo.  My permissions are not 'fixable'.